# Two types of matrix output in C++

Tags: c++

I tried many many times, in different compilers, but had the same result. My question is:

In C++, given `int a[10];` as the declaration of `a`, then `a[0]` and `0[a]` mean the same. I claim that:

```
cout << a[0];
```

is the same as

```
cout << 0[a];
```

Please explain to me why `a[i]` is the same as `i[a]` in C++, where `i` is an integer.

Comment: Maybe you'd better say what type `a` is as well.  Because [the two forms aren't always interchangeable](http://ideone.com/fAO1lj).

Comment: ok))let's say int a[10];

Answer (score 4):

Because array index operations are internally interpreted as `*(a+i)`.

Comment: And not just interpreted; that's how they're **defined** in the language definition.

Comment: @Pete: But for built-in types only.

Comment: @BenVoigt - once you're into user-defined types, the original identity no longer applies, either. But let's not drag this essentially correct answer down a rathole of technicalities.

Comment: @Pete: On the other hand, this question is tagged `c++` and not `c`, so an answer that encompasses user-defined types (or at least states its limits) might be good.

Comment: So, a[i]=i[a] means speed of cout<<a[i]; is the same as the speed of cout<<i[a]; am i understandin right ? I mean it wasn't a more effective way to output

Comment: @Lacoste Yes. Both take same instructions to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I declare an array: `int a[10];` Now `a` represents some memory address at the beginning of where the array is in memory, and you can think of the index as an offset from that memory address.

So when applying the index operation to the array, the value is defined as follows: `a[i] = *(a+i)` By the commutative property of addition, you can see that `a[0] = 0[a]` because of how the index operation is defined by the language.

Comment: `a` may be implemented using an address, but it isn't a pointer.  It does decay to one in this context, however.

Comment: What is it then? I always thought it was the address of the first element of the array

Comment: In `int a[10];` then `a` is an array.  Its type is `int [10]` not `int*`.  Its size is `10 * sizeof(int)` not `sizeof (int*)`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the value of a then?

Comment: The value of `a` is the entire array.  But there's an implicit conversion from an array type to a pointer type, so you can use it anywhere you could use a pointer.  The distinction arises in cases like `sizeof` which work on both arrays and pointers, and since the array case needs no conversion, the compiler will prefer it.